# call onresumo() method within a contentpage XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am having the following problem in
my statement in iOS. I need to activate a command at the moment the user returns to the application when it is in the background. On my `ContentPage` I can not find a method to identify the return. In Android, it works correctly, only in iOS, I can not find any function in the content that shows me that I am returning

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnAppearing()");
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnDisappearing");
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnBindingContextChanged");
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    }
```

I tried the three options but no results

Comment: Is this what you're looking for maybe? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63577/app-onresume-not-called-on-ios

Comment: Onresume is properly called in my App.xaml.cs, to work with my application I would have to call that onresume inside a contentpage

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't realised you were using XF. Silly suggestion maybe but have you tried calling the base method first? :P

Comment: without results, it continues to only cast onResume () in the App. and does not call any content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually do it this way so i don't have to bother with subscriptions:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        if (Application.Current.MainPage is IAppStateAware appStateAwarePage)
            await appStateAwarePage.OnStartApplicationAsync();
        if (Application.Current.MainPage.BindingContext is IAppStateAware appStateAwareVm)
            await appStateAwareVm.OnStartApplicationAsync();
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override async void OnSleep()
    {
        if (Application.Current.MainPage is IAppStateAware appStateAwarePage)
            await appStateAwarePage.OnSleepApplicationAsync();
        if (Application.Current.MainPage.BindingContext is IAppStateAware appStateAwareVm)
            await appStateAwareVm.OnSleepApplicationAsync();
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        if (Application.Current.MainPage is IAppStateAware appStateAwarePage)
            await appStateAwarePage.OnResumeApplicationAsync();
        if (Application.Current.MainPage.BindingContext is IAppStateAware appStateAwareVm)
            await appStateAwareVm.OnResumeApplicationAsync();
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}

public class YourContentPage : Page, IAppStateAware
{
    public Task OnResumeApplicationAsync()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task OnSleepApplicationAsync()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task OnStartApplicationAsync()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IAppStateAware
{
    Task OnResumeApplicationAsync();
    Task OnSleepApplicationAsync();
    Task OnStartApplicationAsync();
}
```

Comment: Why do you do a separate resume for the BindingContext?

Comment: @DavidClarke Because the platform provides the means to do so, so the interface should do so too.

Answer (score 6):

As josemigallas said, you are looking for `App.OnResume()`. You can easily subscribe and unsubscribe to a `MessagingCenter` event which can be sent from your `App.OnResume()` method to trigger actions in each of your `ContentPage`s that are subscribed (do not forget to unsubscribe from the event within `ContentPage.OnDisappearing()` to prevent memory leaks):

In your `ContentPage`s:

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
    Debug.WriteLine("OnAppearing()");
    base.OnAppearing();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "SpecialOnResumeKeyValue", app => {
            //Do something
    };
}

protected override void OnDisappearing() {
    Debug.WriteLine("OnDisappearing");
    base.OnDisappearing();

    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App>(this, "SpecialOnResumeKeyValue"); //VERY IMPORTANT
}
```

Then in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override async void OnResume() {
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "SpecialOnResumeKeyValue");
}
```